# Generics get class name

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

I have a generic function that I would like to get the name of the class that is passed in.

```
public addComponent<T extends Component>(): Component {
    comp = new Component() as T;
    comp.name = T.constructor.name;
    console.log(comp.name);
    return comp;
}
```

Then lets say I call it like so:

```
obj.addComponent<MyClass>();
```

I would then expect the log to display "MyClass". But currently I get an error saying:

> Cannot find name 'T'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do that.

The `T` doesn't exist at runtime, it's only for compilation and the compiler removes that (along with the types) so the resulting javascript for this:

```
class MyFactory {
    public addComponent<T extends Component>(): Component {
        let comp = new Component() as T;
        comp.name = T.constructor.name;
        console.log(comp.name);
        return comp;
    }
}
```

Is:

```
var MyFactory = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyFactory.prototype.addComponent = function () {
        var comp = new Component();
        comp.name = T.constructor.name;
        console.log(comp.name);
        return comp;
    };
    return MyFactory;
}());
```

As you can see, the js code doesn't have the generics signature, so there's no definition for `T`, and so `T.constructor` results in the error you're receiving.

If you want the method to create an instance of a class by passing it then it should look like:

```
interface ComponentConstructor<T extends Component> {
    new(): T;
    name: string;
}

class Component {
    name: string;
}

class MyComponent extends Component {}

class MyFactory {
    public addComponent<T extends Component>(ctor: ComponentConstructor<T>): Component {
        let comp = new ctor();
        comp.name = ctor.name;
        console.log(comp.name);
        return comp;
    }
}

let factory = new MyFactory();
let obj = factory.addComponent(MyComponent as ComponentConstructor<MyComponent>);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ComponentConstructor%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E%20%7B%0A%09new()%3A%20T%3B%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Component%20%7B%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyComponent%20extends%20Component%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyFactory%20%7B%0A%09public%20addComponent%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E(ctor%3A%20ComponentConstructor%3CT%3E)%3A%20Component%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20comp%20%3D%20new%20ctor()%3B%0A%09%09comp.name%20%3D%20ctor.name%3B%0A%09%09console.log(comp.name)%3B%0A%09%09return%20comp%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20factory%20%3D%20new%20MyFactory()%3B%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20factory.addComponent(MyComponent%20as%20ComponentConstructor%3CMyComponent%3E)%3B))

Comment: After I call `addComponent` I do `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));` and for some reason it is only showing the `Components` properties (and it's parents), and not the `MyComponent`'s properties. Why is that?

Comment: Figured it out, it was because the properties in the class were not set.